# .NET Assembly: A bug in gacutil.exe? /f option doesn't seem to do anything

Tags: c#, .net, windows, .net-assembly, gac

So, I was playing around with gacutil command. I wanted to prevent installing the same assembly with the same version to the gac.
I was expecting this by not providing `/f` option.

My test:

Create a class library project name TestGAC.Library:

```
public class Class1
{
    public static string GetText()
    {
        return "Test1 ";
    }
}
```

Create a console App "TestGAC.Console" that display the text from the library:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var text = Class1.GetText();

        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }
```

I'm sining the Classlibrary dll with a strong name.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Set the text to `Test 1` Build and install to the gac using:
   `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\gacutil.exe" /i TestGAC.Library.dll`
2. Test the console: It is displaying the correct text: `Test 1`
3. Change the text to `Test 2` and install it to the gac again wihtout specifying `/f`.
4. Test again the console: It is displaying `Test 2`. Expected result: `Test 1`.

Am I missing something? Why this is not working properly?

I've been using `gacutil` from `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\gacutil.exe"`.

Comment: That's not how it works.  You only use /f if you want to intentionally overwrite a *different* assembly with the same display name.  Your beef is with /i, it simply does not have the feature you want.

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean by _Different_?
Same name with different _publicKeyToken_ ?